# Why do some of my floors have Stars?

Tags: tiny-tower

I started playing Tiny Tower again after not playing for a while, and I noticed that my floors now have Stars. What does that mean? How do I get more stars?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They show how many bitizens are working in their dream job.

Answer (score -3):

They tell you how someone's dream drop got there if that someone is working there.

Answer (score -5):

When you have a star on or under your floor it means that bitizens like to go to that floor a lot